# Azure Devops multistage pipeline or release, when to use what?

Tags: automation, azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

I've started doing some testing using multi-stage pipelines to be able to have the pipeline as code, but I'm getting a bit confused about the usage of the pipeline considering we have Release pipeline as well, and multi-stage pipeline currently can do the release pipeline's job with gates and multiple environments, just in a code based pipeline which I would prefer.

My question is when should each of them be used?

Comment: I'm also interested on people's views on this. My view is that multi-stage azure pipelines would eventually replace the classic release pipeline. Before there was a build and release as separate "concepts" in devOps. Now build is simply called Pipelines and it supports a great amount of CI/CD scenarios, different environments, approval steps, etc. so I don't see any need to use Release pipelines and in my opinion is just a different approach (legacy?) that I won't personally use.

Comment: Basically, YAML is the future. If YAML fits all of your needs, you should use it to be future-proof.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> When should each of them be used?

I strongly agree with iberodev's and Daniel's comments, that **YAML is the future**.  Based on the needs of most developers and users, **YAML** has been the focus of our development work in recent sprints.

But as of now, your choice of what to use should be based on the features supported by each.

---

- **Using YAML with multi-stage:**

Most of time, we recommend you use YAML in multi-stage pipelines. We have provided support for most of the UI features in YAML, including pipeline resource, server job and etc.

Also, YAML still has some features that classic ui pipelines don't, such as **Environments**, Strategies jobs, job outputs, templating and etc. These are all only supported in YAML.

In addition, this is our [latest YAML feature announcement document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=example) and we are still keeping this doc update as we put new features into the product. If the features you need to put into actual use are described in this document, I strongly suggest you use Multi-stage pipeline.

---

- **Using Release pipeline of Classic UI:**

BUT, as I mentioned previously, we are developing but haven't supported all of the classic features in YAML. For example, one key feature in classic UI release pipelines, **Gate**, it is still in progress in development: [Automated checks (gates) between stages](https://dev.azure.com/mseng/AzureDevOpsRoadmap/_workitems/edit/1570285).

When this or other features which haven't been added in YAML are necessary for your team, then you're better off using Release pipeline with classic UI for your product security.

Comment: I'm so glad to have found this - I'm just starting out with Azure DevOps, and had made a nice multi stage YAML CI/CD pipeline (courtesy of MS Learn: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/paths/deploy-applications-with-azure-devops/), but was feeling paranoid that I was missing something fundamental, as I'd done nothing with the 'Releases' tab, and it just seemed to duplicate the work I'd already done in YAML under 'Pipelines'. A little more explanation in the DevOps portal about this might be useful? Thanks anyway.

Comment: I'm also evaluating at an enterprise level whether to pick one route over the other.  My current sticking point is that work-item tracking is available (work item has been deployed to development/testing/staging/production) via the classic Releases product while the mutli-stage pipelines does not offer an out of the box solution to this.  Downstream of this fact would be things such as dashboard widgets and who knows what else that aren't built ontop of the multi-stage pipelines and can't be used with it.

Comment: I created a separate post for my question above which was addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60493017/is-there-a-way-to-update-the-deployment-section-of-a-work-item) - spoiler alert, Releases are the only solution for out-of-the-box work-item tracking.

Comment: For people with OCD - You can remove the releases menu item by disabling the creation of classic build/release pipelines. 

Project Settings: Pipelines > Settings 
Disable creation of classic build|release pipelines