# Is there a way to update the 'Deployment' section of a work item?

Tags: azure-devops

Does anyone know of a way to update the 'Deployment' section of a work item?  I haven't been able to find any working examples of tasks that can do this, cli commands or API calls.  This seems to be an exclusive feature of Azure DevOps Releases product; but I would like to be able to implement something similar using the multi-stage YAML pipelines.

[image: Deployment section updated via Releases product]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The release deployments control shows release information for those work items that have been associated to a commit which is part of a build being released.

The release deployments control **currently works with classic release pipelines and with Azure DevOps Services (cloud) only**.

How to Configure:

First thing you must do is configure the release definition to post deployment information back to Azure Boards.

1. Open Release definition, Options and Integrations

[image]

2. Select the "Preview: Report deployment status to Boards" option and
   **configure the stages and deployment types**

[image]

Now any release status changes will auto updated in  'Deployment' section of that related work item.

For details please kindly refer our official doc here-- [Link work items to deployments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/work-items/work-item-deployments-control?view=azure-devops)

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I understand how to do it as shown in the screenshots I provided.  However, I was looking for validation that the Releases product was currently the only way to enable out-of-the-box work-item tracking in Azure DevOps.

Comment: @TheBuildGuy Sorry, according to the official doc, it's the only way to handle this at the moment.